# transformar números de listas em números de uma matriz em python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matriz

Não consigo pegar os elementos passados pelo usuário e transformar numa matriz, sempre tá dando erro em algo.

> Faça um programa que receba entradas inteiras do usuário enquanto ele não digitar ”s”, sem aspas, e as adicione em uma lista.
> A seguir leia dois números, indicando, respectivamente, o número de
> linhas L e o número de colunas C que a matriz resultante deve ter.
> Você deve converter a lista dada em uma matriz de L linhas e C colunas, em que os C primeiros números correspondem à primeira linha, os C seguintes correspondem à segunda linha, etc.
> Caso a quantidade de números fornecidos não for igual à quantidade de números necessários para a criação da matriz, seu programa deve escrever apenas ”IMPOSSIVEL”, sem aspas e sem acento.

Meu código está assim até o momento, qualquer alteração vou mudando aqui também.

```
lista = []

linhas = int(input('Digite um número de linhas: '))
colunas = int(input('Digite um número de colunas: '))

while True:
    n = input('Digite um número: ')
    if n == 's':
        break
    lista.append(int(n))
print(lista)


if len(lista) == linhas * colunas:
    matriz = []
    for i in range(linhas):
        for j in range(colunas):
            lista[i] = lista[i][j]
    matriz.append(lista[i], end=' ')
else:
    print('IMPOSSIVEL')
print(matriz)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tem vários problemas no seu código, um deles é fazer `lista[i][j]`. Como `lista` é uma lista de números, então `lista[i]` é um número, e portanto não tem como acessar a posição `j` deste número. Mas mesmo que pudesse, a lógica está errada.

**Como você já verificou antes se o tamanho da lista está correto**, você não precisa mais de 2 *loops* aninhados. Basta iterar pela lista, e quando a quantidade de elementos completar uma linha, você adiciona na matriz e começa uma nova linha:

```py
matriz = []
if len(lista) == linhas * colunas:
    linha = [] # criar uma nova linha
    for n in lista: # para cada elemento da lista
        linha.append(n) # adicionar na linha
        if len(linha) == colunas: # se já deu a quantidade de colunas, é porque a linha está preenchida
            matriz.append(linha) # adiciona a linha na matriz
            linha = [] # começa uma nova linha
else:
    print('IMPOSSIVEL')
```

---

Outra forma é você quebrar a lista em várias sub-listas (cujos tamanhos são a quantidade de colunas), usando a [sintaxe de *slice*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211):

```py
matriz = []
if len(lista) == linhas * colunas:
    for i in range(0, len(lista), colunas):
        matriz.append(lista[i: i + colunas])
else:
    print('IMPOSSIVEL')
```

No caso, o `range` percorre a lista, porém em vez de avançar de um em um, ele avança de `colunas` em `colunas`. Depois, o *slice* `[i: i + colunas]` cria uma sub-lista cujo tamanho é a quantidade de colunas.

Outra forma de fazer é usando [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](/q/192343/112052):

```py
if len(lista) == linhas * colunas:
    matriz = [ lista[i: i + colunas] for i in range(0, len(lista), colunas) ]
else:
    print('IMPOSSIVEL')
```

Lembrando que **estas soluções funcionam porque você verificou o tamanho da lista antes**, por isso temos certeza que não sobrarão nem faltarão elementos na matriz. Se a ideia fosse adicionar elementos, porém tomar alguma ação no caso de sobrar ou faltar, aí teria que incluir esta verificação dos elementos restantes (ou faltantes), e tomar alguma ação em cada caso.

---

Por fim, outra solução (meio *overkill*, mas fica como curiosidade) é:

```py
if len(lista) == linhas * colunas:
    matriz = list(map(list, zip(*[iter(lista)] * colunas)))
else:
    print('IMPOSSIVEL')
```

Esta solução é baseada em uma das ["receitas" do módulo `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) (porém lá é uma solução mais genérica, já aqui eu simplifiquei porque verificamos antes que o tamanho da lista é adequado, e não precisa de tudo que tem lá).

Answer (score 0):

o segredo é que você precisa de uma lista temporária que vc vai adicionar cada elemento da lista, e depois você adiciona a lista temporária na matriz:

```
if len(lista) == linhas * colunas:
    matriz = []
    for i in range(linhas):
        lista_temp = []
        for j in range(colunas):
            lista_temp.append(lista[i*colunas+j])
        matriz.append(lista_temp)
    print(matriz)
else:
    print('IMPOSSIVEL')
```

tem esse trecho que diz `lista_temp.append(lista[i*colunas+j])` isso porque a lista tem todos os elementos da matriz planificados, e você precisa saber onde da lista está elemento (i,j)